# Entity Framework 6 Exception type 'System.TypeInitializationException'

Tags: entity-framework-6

After upgrading from EF5 to EF6 I get a System.TypeInitializationException

The inner message says:

```
    An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for entityFramework: Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

All of the posts that I found about this exception says that I need to correct the version on my Web.config file and it is set at Version=6.0.0.0

```
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Core.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

I still get this exception after changing the version to 6.0.0.0, any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: Did you follow [this upgrade procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/upgradeef6.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, still no luck. @GertArnold